# Casimir force, even dimension

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, casimir-effect

Considering a Scalar field (massless) in a $D$ dimensional space, with Dirichlet boundary condition in $x$ direction,
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(0,x_2,x_3,....x_D,t)=\phi(a,x_2,x_3,...x_D,t)
\end{eqnarray}
So, the momenta could be defined as,
\begin{eqnarray}
\vec{p}=\{ \frac{n \pi}{a},p_2,p_3,,.......p_D \}
=\{ \frac{n \pi}{a}, \vec{p_1}\}
\end{eqnarray}
where, $n\in Z^+ $.
Now the Hamiltonian,
\begin{eqnarray}
H=\sum_n \int \frac{d^{D-1} \vec{p_1} }{(2\pi)^{D-1} } \omega_{\vec{p}} (a_{\vec{p}} ^{\dagger}a_{\vec{p}} +\frac{1}{2})
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray}
E_{vac}=\left\langle 0 \middle| H \middle| 0 \right\rangle \sim \sum_n \int \frac{d^{D-1} \vec{p_1} }{(2\pi)^{D-1} } \frac{\omega_{\vec{p}}}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
We will use Zeta function regularization technique to regularize it,
Defining,
\begin{eqnarray}
E(s)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_n \int \frac{d^{D-1} \vec{p_1} }{(2\pi)^{D-1} } \omega_{\vec{p}} (l\omega_{\vec{p}} )^{-s}
\end{eqnarray}
The finite part of vacuum energy,
\begin{eqnarray}
E_{vac}'=\lim_{s\rightarrow 0} E(s)
\end{eqnarray}
Doing some algebra, we find out
\begin{eqnarray}
E(s)=l^{-s} \frac{V}{a ({4\pi})^{\frac{D-1}{2}}}(\frac{\pi}{a})^{D-s} \frac{ \Gamma (\frac{s-D}{2})}{\Gamma( \frac{s-1}{2}) }\zeta(s-D)
\end{eqnarray}
Here, $\zeta(s)$ is the Zeta function. In the limit $s\rightarrow 0$, $D$ being even $D=2p$, with $p>0$ and $p$ is an integer,
\begin{eqnarray}
E'_{vac}\propto \zeta(-2p)=0.
\end{eqnarray}
**My question:** Can you please elaborate the reason, why vacuum energy is zero in even dimension for scalar fields for such geometry where one direction is finite and the rest $D-1$ direction is infinite? May be picking $D=2$, which will result in a infinite slab like geometry.

Comment: relevant: [105635](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105635/which-values-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-at-negative-arguments-come-up-in-physi/312370#312370)

Comment: The result is not zero because $\Gamma(-D/2)$ blows up. You can use the reflection formula for $\zeta$ to rewrite this in terms of positive argument, and it'll be a manifestly nonzero finite number.